# Reading & Writing JSON file on Google Cloud Storage using Python

Tags: python, json, flask, google-cloud-storage

As said, I have a JSON file on a Cloud Storage bucket, is there a way to read (and modify) its content via Python?

```
@app.route("/myform/", methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def myform():
    form = MyForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
       return redirect('/')
    return render_template('my_form.html', form=form)
```

I would like to read a JSON on Google Cloud Storage and add to it the value defined by the form (a key and its value).

This is all on a Flask webapp running on a standard AppEngine.

Answer (score 3):

Google Cloud Platform (GCP) has a sample Bookshelf [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/tutorial-app) that shows how to store persistent data on [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/using-cloud-datastore) using Flask framework in Python. Here is an example on how to create, read, update, and delete (CRUD) data stored in Cloud Storage.

Create:

```
@crud.route('/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.form.to_dict(flat=True)
        book = get_model().create(data)
        return redirect(url_for('.view', id=book['id']))
    return render_template("form.html", action="Add", book={})
```

Read:

```
@crud.route("/")
def list():
    token = request.args.get('page_token', None)
    if token:
        token = token.encode('utf-8')
    books, next_page_token = get_model().list(cursor=token)
    return render_template(
        "list.html",
        books=books,
        next_page_token=next_page_token)
```

Update:

```
@crud.route('/<id>/edit', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit(id):
    book = get_model().read(id)
if request.method == 'POST':
    data = request.form.to_dict(flat=True)
    book = get_model().update(data, id)
    return redirect(url_for('.view', id=book['id']))
return render_template("form.html", action="Edit", book=book)
```

Delete:

```
@crud.route('/<id>/delete')
def delete(id):
    get_model().delete(id)
    return redirect(url_for('.list'))
```

You can find more details on GCPs JSON API reference [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects).

Comment: Confused about this answer as far as the Google example app - that example uses Cloud Storage only for static assets like images. The CRUD operations are done with Cloud Datastore, NOT Cloud Storage https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/using-cloud-storage   I am pretty sure you can not simply use a JSON file as a CRUD datastore unless you are using some sort of database library - this is called an "Embedded Database". I have played with a Java embedded JSON database called JsonDb, still looking for a Python equivalent; TinyDB looks similar.